# Returning multiple values from Python Dict with range of datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, dictionary

I'm running into a problem with using DateTime as a dict key.  My goal is to bring in information from one data source that includes Datetime, and then look up in a dictionary and return all values for keys that are within 2 days +- of the input DateTime.

For example, my input would be:
`datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 20, 12, 48)`

My dictionary to reference would be:
`example = {datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 20, 14, 43):'A', datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 18, 19, 41):'B', datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 9, 12):'C'}`

In that case, I would return: `A, B`

I have considered sorting the dictionary and then creating a dictionary of indexes maybe for odd-numbered dates, then taking in my input date, figuring the base date +- 2 of the input date, referencing the index dict, and then using those indexes to loop through the reference dict only between the indexes and return all values that are there.

My main issue is that I can't predict what the dict datetimes will be or the input datetimes so I'm just not certain if I can return values for a range of keys in a dict other than by looping through the index of the keys in a sorted order.  Doing a for loop for all keys is not efficient here because of the number of keys to look through -- I am already reducing this list by deduplicating down as much as possible and only bringing in the minimum amount of reference data.

One other item is that my inputs will be 100,000s of datetimes to look up, many of which will be minutes, seconds, or hours off from each other, so reducing the number of lookups and for looping will be essential to keep the runtime down.

I apologize if this isn't quite a proper question with full code to look at but I basically am not sure where to start on this issue, so I didn't think it would help anyone to put anything else in except for example input and dictionary with output goal.

Comment: Read about [datetime.datetime.timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

Comment: Have you considered using a SQL database ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use an SQL database, I am restricted to the data model that I showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, sort the dictionary dates and transform a dictionary into list of sorted tuples :

  ```
  dic_dates = {
      datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 20, 14, 43):'A',
      datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 18, 12, 41):'B',
      datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 15, 9, 12):'C'
  }

  sorted_dates = sorted(dic_dates.items())
  ```
- Then use bisect to find the position of your date inside that list :

  ```
  dat = datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 20, 12, 48)
  insert_index = bisect.bisect_left(sorted_dates, (dat,None))
  ```
- Look from this position to the left and break as soon as an element do not verify the condition, then do the same starting from the position to the right. (You can use your own conditions as I found that was quite unclear in you example - +-2days should not select 'B' IMO but that's not the point)

  ```
  if insert_index:
  #if insert_index = 0, do not loop on left side
      dat_min = dat - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
      for d in sorted_dates[insert_index-1::-1]:
          if d[0] > dat_min:
              print(d[1])
          else:
              break

  dat_max = dat + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
  for d in sorted_dates[insert_index:]:
      if d[0] < dat_max:
          print(d[1])
      else:
          break
  ```

### EDIT

One example of bisct_left implementation :

```
def bisect_left(l, e, start = 0):
    if not l:
        return start
    pos = int(len(l)/2)
    if l[pos] < e and (pos+1 >= len(l) or l[pos+1] > e):
        return start + pos + 1
    elif l[pos] >= e:
        return bisect_left(l[:pos], e, start)
    else:
        return bisect_left(l[pos:], e, start+pos)
```

I strongly advice you to use bisect as it will be quicker and more reliable.

Comment: I think that this will work and is very similar to what I was thinking as well.  At the moment, the bisect module is not allowed.  I have asked for it to be turned back on but until then, do you know of another way to quickly find a list index?

Comment: Also you're right that B isn't actually within but I was just writing in some quick dates and didn't do the math correctly in my head.  My actual conditions will be more than 2 days but I was trying to simplify.  I'll modify my example dates to be within so people in the future aren't confused.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 I edited - you can also use searchsorted from numpy if you have numpy

Comment: Your code works perfectly with your modification until I can get bisect() turned on.  It is having trouble completing right now doing about 110,000 rounds of it.  I'm looking at ways I can split the time down further.  My data is actually key:['item1','item2'].  My goal is to use item1 to return a list of item2 that appear, but only for the records within 5 days +- of the input date.  I'm matching item1 exactly from an input mixed with date.  Could I create different dictionaries -> sorted tuples with names based on item1 without knowing in advance what all item1 are?